# How can I remove these global variables and show the increments as they happen?

Tags: javascript, function, arrow-functions

I can't figure out how I can run this code without using these two global variables `computerScore` and `playerScore`. If I declare them in the function the values reset to 0 each time it runs.

Also, how do I show the increments at the time of `return`? As it stands right now the values are only updated after the function is called again.

```
const getPlayerChoice = (userChoice) => {
    userChoice = userChoice.toLowerCase();
    if (
        userChoice === "rock" ||
        userChoice === "paper" ||
        userChoice === "scissor"
    ) {
        return userChoice;
    } else {
        console.log("Invalid option.");
    }
};

const computerPlay = () => {
    let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);
    if (randomNumber === 0) {
        return "scissor";
    } else if (randomNumber === 1) {
        return "rock";
    } else if (randomNumber === 2) {
        return "paper";
    }
};
let computerScore = 0;
let playerScore = 0;
let tie = 0;

const playRound = (playerSelection, computerSelection) => {
    playerSelection = playerSelection.toLowerCase();

    let currentScores =
        "Computer: " +
        computerScore +
        " Player: " +
        playerScore +
        " Tie: " +
        tie;

    if (playerSelection.toLowerCase() === computerSelection) {
        ++tie;
        return "It's a tie\n" + currentScores;
    }

    if (playerSelection.toLowerCase() === "scissor") {
        if (computerSelection === "rock") {
            ++computerScore;
            return "Computer wins!\n" + currentScores;
        } else {
            ++playerScore;
            return "You win!\n" + currentScores;
        }
    }

    if (playerSelection.toLowerCase() === "paper") {
        if (computerSelection === "scissor") {
            ++computerScore;
            return "Computer wins!\n" + currentScores;
        } else {
            ++playerScore;
            return "You win!\n" + currentScores;
        }
    }

    if (playerSelection.toLowerCase() === "rock") {
        if (computerSelection === "paper") {
            ++computerScore;
            return "Computer wins!\n" + currentScores;
        } else {
            ++playerScore;
            return "You win!\n" + currentScores;
        }
    }
};

const game = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        let playerSelection = getPlayerChoice(
            prompt("Choose between rock, paper, scissor")
        );
        if (playerSelection == null) {
            alert("Invalid. Try again.");
            --i;
            continue;
        }
        const computerSelection = computerPlay();
        console.log(`You chose: ${playerSelection.toLowerCase()}`);
        console.log(`Computer chose: ${computerSelection}`);
        console.log(
            playRound(playerSelection.toLowerCase(), computerSelection)
        );
    }
    if (playerScore > computerScore) {
        console.log("Congratulations! You beat the Computer!");
    } else if (computerScore > playerScore) {
        console.log("Sorry! You lost.");
    } else {
        console.log("You tied with the Computer.");
    }
};

game();
```

Comment: A few general tips: set ESLint, it will show you some great best practices. Then learn to use debugging in Chrome console; you can put breakpoints in your js code, then step through it line by line, examining variables as the code runs. Both extremely, extremely helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I did some refactor in your code and these are some recommendation are:

1. use const in the variables that you don't need to reassign, for example, currentScores.
2. don't reassign function parameters values, instead, create a new variable with the modified value.
3. Don't Repeat Yourself, for example, playerSelection is used several times with toLowerCase(), instead you can save this value in lowerCase in a variable
4. Use template literals instead of + to concatenate variables and strings
5. Since you will use this variables encapsulated in this script, isn't a problem that you let it globally and also, this variables are used by all methods in the script, if for some reason you need let it in a specific scope, you can use an IIFE https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE

```js
// Rock paper or Scissors code

(function rockPaperOrScissors() {
  let computerScore = 0;
  let playerScore = 0;

  const getPlayerChoice = userChoice => {
    const lowercaseChoice = userChoice.toLowerCase();
    const options = ["rock", "paper", "scissor"];
    if (options.includes(lowercaseChoice)) {
      return userChoice;
    } else {
      console.log("Invalid option.");
    }
  };

  const computerPlay = () => {
    let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);

    if (randomNumber === 0) {
      return "scissor";
    } else if (randomNumber === 1) {
      return "rock";
    } else if (randomNumber === 2) {
      return "paper";
    }
  };

  const setComputerWinner = () => {
    computerScore += 1;
    const computerWinsText = `Computer wins!\nComputer: ${computerScore} Player: ${playerScore}`;

    return computerWinsText;
  };

  const setHumanWinner = () => {
    playerScore += 1;
    const humanWinsText = `You win!\nComputer: ${computerScore} Player: ${playerScore}`;

    return humanWinsText;
  };

  const playRound = (playerSelection, computerSelection) => {
    const lowerCasePlayer = playerSelection.toLowerCase();

    const tieText = `It's a tie\nComputer: ${computerScore} Player: ${playerScore}`;

    if (lowerCasePlayer === computerSelection) {
      return tieText;
    }

    if (lowerCasePlayer === "scissor") {
      if (computerSelection === "rock") {
        return setComputerWinner();
      } else {
        return setHumanWinner();
      }
    }

    if (lowerCasePlayer === "paper") {
      if (computerSelection === "scissor") {
        return setComputerWinner();
      } else {
        return setHumanWinner();
      }
    }

    if (lowerCasePlayer === "rock") {
      if (computerSelection === "paper") {
        return setComputerWinner();
      } else {
        return setHumanWinner();
      }
    }
  };

  const game = () => {
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
      let playerSelection = getPlayerChoice(
        prompt("Choose between rock, paper, scissor")
      );
      if (playerSelection == null) {
        alert("Invalid. Try again.");
        --i;
        continue;
      }
      const computerSelection = computerPlay();

      console.log(`You chose: ${playerSelection.toLowerCase()}`);
      console.log(`Computer chose: ${computerSelection}`);
      console.log(playRound(playerSelection.toLowerCase(), computerSelection));
    }
    if (playerScore > computerScore) {
      console.log("Congratulations! You beat the Computer!");
    } else if (computerScore > playerScore) {
      console.log("Sorry! You lost.");
    } else {
      console.log("You tied with the Computer.");
    }
  };
  game();
})();
```

Comment: I had to place ```currentScores``` with ```computerScore``` and ```playerScore``` to avoid an error. However, when I run the game the scores do not increase even after the function is called again. The scores stay at ```Computer: 0 Player: 0```

Comment: You can upload your code to codesanbox or something like that?

Comment: Here it is. https://codesandbox.io/s/rock-paper-scissor-wpjqh

Comment: The problem was that if you declare currentScores at the init of the script, and don't update it's value, it doesn't will be updated when the variables change, it just will get the first value (Computer 0, Player 0), since it will be all the time updated, I just add it to the computerWinsText variable, this is the code =>  https://codesandbox.io/s/rock-paper-scissor-0nkun?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Thank you so much! This did exactly what I was looking for. Interesting to see I didn't even need the ```currentScores``` variable. I'm a little confused about how moving it to ```computerWinsText``` and ```humanWinsText``` made it stay updated. Would you be able to explain that a bit?

Comment: Sure, it stay updated because before I give a value to humanWinsText  ot computerWinsText, I update the playerScore or the humanScore, and the reason why it is reassigned a constant without problems, is that the functions setComupterWinner and setHumanWinner are removed from memory every time I return a value inside them.

Answer (score 1):

Return an object with who won and print the win message from your computerWins and playerWins functions. Pass in the current score so you can print it but track it in your `game()` function. Here is working and tested code without your global variables

```
    const getPlayerChoice = userChoice => {
        const lowercaseChoice = userChoice.toLowerCase();
        const options = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissor'];
        if (options.includes(lowercaseChoice)) {
            return userChoice;
        } else {
            console.log('Invalid option.');
        }
    };

    const computerPlay = () => {
        let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3);

        if (randomNumber === 0) {
            return 'scissor';
        } else if (randomNumber === 1) {
            return 'rock';
        } else if (randomNumber === 2) {
            return 'paper';
        }
    };

    const computerWins = (totalComputerScore, totalPlayerScore) => {
        totalComputerScore += 1;
        console.log(`Computer wins!\nComputer: ${totalComputerScore} Player: ${totalPlayerScore}`);
        return {playerScore: totalPlayerScore, computerScore: totalComputerScore};
    };

    const playerWins = (totalComputerScore, totalPlayerScore) => {
        totalPlayerScore += 1;
        console.log(`You win!\nComputer: ${totalComputerScore} Player: ${totalPlayerScore}`);
        return {playerScore: totalPlayerScore, computerScore: totalComputerScore};
    };

    const tie = (totalComputerScore, totalPlayerScore) => {
        console.log(`It's a tie\nComputer: ${totalComputerScore} Player: ${totalPlayerScore}`);
        return {playerScore: totalPlayerScore, computerScore: totalComputerScore};
    };

    const playRound = (playerSelection, computerSelection, totalComputerScore, totalPlayerScore) => {
        const lowerCasePlayer = playerSelection.toLowerCase();

        if (lowerCasePlayer === 'scissor') {
            if (computerSelection === 'rock') {
                return computerWins(totalComputerScore, totalPlayerScore);
            } else if(computerSelection !== 'scissor') {
                return playerWins(totalComputerScore, totalPlayerScore);
            } else {
                return tie(totalComputerScore, totalPlayerScore);
            }
        }

        if (lowerCasePlayer === 'paper') {
            if (computerSelection === 'scissor') {
                return computerWins(totalComputerScore, totalPlayerScore);
            } else if(computerSelection !== 'paper') {
                return playerWins(totalComputerScore, totalPlayerScore);
            } else {
                return tie(totalComputerScore, totalPlayerScore);
            }
        }

        if (lowerCasePlayer === 'rock') {
            if (computerSelection === 'paper') {
                return computerWins(totalComputerScore, totalPlayerScore);
            } else if (computerSelection !== 'rock') {
                return playerWins(totalComputerScore, totalPlayerScore);
            } else {
                return tie(totalComputerScore, totalPlayerScore);
            }
        }
    };

    const game = () => {
        let totalPlayerScore = 0;
        let totalComputerScore = 0;

        for (let i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
            let playerSelection = getPlayerChoice(
                prompt('Choose between rock, paper, scissor')
            );
            if (playerSelection == null) {
                alert('Invalid. Try again.');
                --i;
                continue;
            }
            const computerSelection = computerPlay();

            console.log(`You chose: ${playerSelection.toLowerCase()}`);
            console.log(`Computer chose: ${computerSelection}`);
            const scores = playRound(playerSelection.toLowerCase(), computerSelection, totalComputerScore, totalPlayerScore);
            totalPlayerScore = scores.playerScore;
            totalComputerScore = scores.computerScore;

        }
        if (totalPlayerScore > totalComputerScore) {
            console.log('Congratulations! You beat the Computer!');
        } else if (totalComputerScore > totalPlayerScore) {
            console.log('Sorry! You lost.');
        } else {
            console.log('You tied with the Computer.');
        }
    };
    game();
```

Comment: I'll edit the original post with the entire code. Maybe you could help me fix those functions as well?

Comment: tested. Scores only stay at ```Computer: 1(or 0) Player: 0(or 1)```. Doesn't seem like it's adding value only setting it.

Comment: I updated my code using your working code. My example now works.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't hardcore numbers, use variables in your for loop. Use var instead of let. Var is defined throughout the entire program. I get your problem. Your current scores are not being updated. Instead, make current scores a function that will return the current player score and computer score.